# What's the simplest way to add additional HTML in Django forms and override form layout?

Tags: django-templates

I have a form set up using Django's form facilities and it gets rendered in the template like so:

```
{% block content %}
    <h1>Register to join Forge Design</h1>
    <form method="post" action="">
       {% csrf_token %}
       {{ form.as_p }}
       <input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Submit' %}" />
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

I have the fields First name, Last name, Email and Available date, which will render out my fields vertically with their labels left aligned. What I would like is to control each field such that I will have a layout like in the screenshot below:

[Desired form layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5K3aF.png)

Could anyone best advise how to customise so that I can intersperse labels in between fields such as the "Name" and "Email Address *" and change the positioning of the first and last name labels so that they sit below their respective fields. Is this something I must do by replacing in the template {{form.as_p}} with the individual {{form fields}} and then wrapping that in a div to be controlled by CSS?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access to each field by name define in your form

```
{{ form.first_name.errors }} # Error of your field first name
{{ form.first_name.label_tag }} # Label of your field first name, generate a label tag
{{ form.first_name }} # Input for your field first name
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually

Comment: Thanks @Wilfried I think I will go with this method

Comment: Don't forget to accept answer if that help you. Glad to help you.